# Reading file in hex gives wrong output (skips some hex values)

Tags: c++, file-io, hex, emulation, hexdump

I'm trying to read/print out the hex instructions from the Chip8 version of Pong (which can be downloaded [here](http://www.zophar.net/pdroms/chip8/chip-8-games-pack.html)).
Here is the code I am using to read in ROM:

```
//Open ROM
string dir = "Test/PONG";
ifstream inf(dir.c_str(), ios::binary);

unsigned char input;
for(int i = 0; inf >> input; i++) {
    //Each loop prints 1 bytes
    //New line every 16 bytes and print line number
    if(i%16 == 0) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << setw(7) << setfill('0') << i << " ";
    }
    //2 extra spaces after 8 bytes
    else if(i%8 == 0)
        cout << "  ";
    cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)input << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

And here's part of the output:

```
0000000 6a 02 6b 6c 3f 6d a2 ea   da b6 dc d6 6e 00 22 d4  
0000010 66 03 68 02 60 60 f0 15   f0 07 30 00 12 1a c7 17  
0000020 77 08 69 ff a2 f0 d6 71   a2 ea da b6 dc d6 60 01
```

...

And here's the output that I believe is correct which I got from running the command "hexdump -C PONG" in the terminal:

```
00000000  6a 02 6b 0c 6c 3f 6d 0c  a2 ea da b6 dc d6 6e 00  
00000010  22 d4 66 03 68 02 60 60  f0 15 f0 07 30 00 12 1a  
00000020  c7 17 77 08 69 ff a2 f0  d6 71 a2 ea da b6 dc d6
```

...

On the first line of hex values, you can see the value '0c' twice in terminal but the output of the code skips printing '0c'. I'm not sure why my code is skipping '0c'. Am I reading the file improperly? Is the command "hexdump" providing the wrong output? What can I change about the way I read the file?

EDIT: Using inf.get(input) is able to read in '0c' however it also outputs some hex values differently.
For example:

```
6a 02 6b 0c 6c 3f 6d 0c ffffffa2 ffffffea ffffffda ffffffb6 ffffffdc ffffffd6 6e 00 22 ffffffd4 66 03 68 02 60 60 fffffff0
```

EDIT 2: The 'f's are printed since some hex values are read as negative numbers. <strike>So I made an if statement that checks if input is negative, if it is negative I multiply it by -1 then print the hex value.</strike>

EDIT 3: I decided to use a stringstream to only print out the last 2 characters for negative hex values:

```
stringstream convert;
if((int)input < 0) {
     convert << hex << (int)input;
     cout << convert.str().substr(6,8) << " ";
     convert.str("");
}
```

EDIT 4: The hex '0c' represents the escape sequence '\f' and is therefore ignored when printing. Using `inf.get(input)` instead of `inf >> input` stores characters into input as unformatted characters (I think). However the `get()` function can't take a `unsigned char` as an argument. So I have to cast input to `char&`.
In conclusion, I had to change `inf >> input` to `inf.get((char&)input)`.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Comment: Maybe the fact that character 0c is ASCII for form feed has something to do with your output

Comment: I was thinking the same but '08' is represents backspace however when '08' is read from the file, it still shows the correct output. Although you may still be right in which case I ask: How can I force '0c' to be printed? Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Comment: Have you tryed to use inf.get(input) instead?

Comment: Now it seems to be working although now the output looks like this: 6a 02 6b 0c 6c 3f 6d 0c ffffffa2 ffffffea ffffffda. It adds 6 'f's in front of some hex values.

Comment: It seems something happens when you add the extra space after 8 bytes. Have you edited the program someway differently from what posted?

Comment: I had to change input from being a unsigned to char to get inf.get(input) to work. Other than that I didn't change anything.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please, check it to see if it works.

Comment: @Bob__ I can't get it to work, I get the error: `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::get(char)'`. No matter what I do, when I call 'inf.get(input)', input has to be char otherwise it won't work (maybe I'm doing something wrong?).

Comment: @Bob__ I finally figured it out! I have to cast input to char& instead of char so the code looks like this `inf.get((char&)input)`. Which confuses since a char is an acceptable argument for the get function. I'll mark your answer as correct since your answer helped me the most in finding out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator>> reads formatted data (char in your case) from the input stream, so a char with value 12 (0c in hex) is considered as ASCII form feed and ignored ( as a value of 32 or 0x20 would be considered a space ).
Char are also signed values and an hex value of a2 (which is decimal 162) would be stored as a negative value. Promoting that value to an int would keep the sign and due to complementation, when printed as unsigned you'll get the ffff's.

keep the

```
unsigned char input;
```

then to read the values use

```
inf.get(static_cast<char>(input))
```

and to print

```
cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int>(input) << " ";
```

Comment: I tried casting input to an unsigned int but the 'f's are still being printed.

Comment: I think the problem may be that some hex values are read (or stored) as negative. I made a temporary solution using a stringstream to only print out the last 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `(signed) int` as your variable.  When a `signed int` is negative and printed in hex, it will be preceded by one or more `F` digits.

I highly recommend using `unsigned int` for your values.

Comment: When I make it unsigned I get the following error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::get(unsigned char&)' I'm not really sure how to fix it. EDIT: I read your answer wrong, I thought you wanted me to make input into an unsigned char. However making input into an unsigned int gives me a similar error.